# YUIcompressor on Webstorm error: CreateProcess error=193, %1

Tags: css, webstorm

I'm getting this error when trying to minify css with YUIcompressor in Webstorm with filewatchers:

```
CreateProcess error=193, %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida
```

translation:

```
CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a Win32 valid application
```

My configuration is the same as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fe14-21NTGU so it should be right... Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings/Tools/File Watchers and double-click on the YUI Compressor JS/CSS file watcher.

Edit "Program" path by adding ".cmd" to end of the filepath.

i.e.: 'AppData\Roaming\npm\yuicompressor.cmd'